# I don't want to postback my .aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, postback

I want to go from the `First.aspx` page to the `second.aspx` page without postback. How should I handle this situation? Is it possible or not?
I am doing this, but I don't know how to get a response from the handler.

Sending a request to handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqure.js"></script>
 function goMoz() { 
      $.post("Handler1.ashx", callback);
      function callback(data) { 
      alert(data);
    }
</script>
```

In the body of the html I'm using html `<a id="buton" onclick="goMoz()">`

What must I do in the handler to go to the `second.aspx` page?

I am also using `window.location = "Registration.aspx";` in `goMoz()`.

Comment: What doesn't work with `window.location = "Registration.aspx";`? This shouldn't cause a postback.

Comment: I mean to say with window.location = "Second.aspx"; my request first go to server then response me.....! and my page is post-back. Some one told me u can use context.request.response from the handler..But i dont no how it is...!

Comment: window.location will cause a full roundtrip and a full page refresh, but *not* a postback. But maybe the full page refresh is what you're trying to avoid, so I added an answer that shows how to update only a part of the page.

Comment: @MountainLion Please don't add useless emojis like that.

Comment: @DonaldDuck: As I explained to abccd, it was totally unintentional. I am _very_ sorry, and I will never do it again (I really didn't want to in the first place). I've already been grilled over it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things: first, your javascript example code has syntax errors, you're missing a closing }.

Second: If you want to load the content of a different page and use the content inside the current page, check out the different [Ajax functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) in jquery, for example the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
   function goMoz() {
       $.post("Handler1.ashx", callback);

       function callback(data) {
           alert(data);
           // Load response of "second.aspx" 
           // into element with ID results.
           $("#results").load("second.aspx");
       }
   }
```

Note that you should be careful when loading a "whole page" into an element of the current page. If the "whole page" contains full HTML markup with html, body etc. tags then your HTML can easily become invalid. You can however define what part of the page to actually grab and insert in the current page by adding a selector after the url:

```
$("#results").load("second.aspx #whatToLoad");
```

This would only load the content of whatToLoad element in the results element on the current page.

Answer (score 0):

in aspx page

```
 function goMoz(islem) {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../Handler1.ashx",
                    data: "islem=" + islem,
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (data) {

                      alert(data)

                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert("Error")
                    }
                });
        };
```

in ashx handeler.

```
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string isl= context.Request.Form["islem"];
             .....same codes
            context.Response.Write("return values");


          }
```

Hope it helpful

Comment: Look my handler is already working...! i want to know how i pass the response of second.aspx like context.Response.Write("second.aspx"); or some thing like that. thnx